# How to read a stop word list from a text file in R

Tags: r, text-mining, stop-words

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read a Text File into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804292/read-a-text-file-into-r)

I have a custom stopword list which is in a text file separated with newline character.How can I use the that file in my R script?

**Code:**

```
my_stopwords <- c(stopwords(),"aint","wanna","gonna",...)
```

The only problem is I want to read the words from the file instead of hardcoding them like above. My text file looks like this:

```
"aint"
"wanna"
"gonna"
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new-line-separated file could technically be considered a valid CSV file. Try `read.csv()` to get the list in as a data.frame. You may want to `unlist` it or just access the first column to get it in an array like what you have.

Comment: Thanks, I can read the file now but how can I get the second column of it , Because the first column contains number of rows and I don't want it.

Comment: `readCSV` isn't even a function in base R. I think you are looking for `read.csv`.

Comment: @Sina: The row numbers you see when you print a dataframe aren't actually treated as a column. Getting the first column of the dataframe, e.g. with `df[, 1]`, should still give you the words.

Answer (score 3):

`readLines` could work here:

```
con <- file("filename.txt", "r")
readLines(con)
```

Although now that you specify that the words are "quoted", it is probably not that great a solution and you would be better off using `read.csv("filename.txt")`