# converting json file into R/text file without execution

Tags: json, r, rstudio

Rstudio has crashed while working and the unsaved files were not able to be loaded into the session. But the files are available in the JSON format. An example,

```
{
    "contents" : "library(hgu133a.db)\nx <- hgu133aENSEMBL\nx\nlength(x)\ncount.mappedkeys(x)\nx[1:3]\nlinks(x[1:3])\n\n## Keep only the mapped keys\nkeys(x) <- mappedkeys(x)\nlength(x)\ncount.mappedkeys(x)\nx # now it is a submap\n\n## The above subsetting can also be achieved with\nx <- hgu133aENSEMBL[mappedkeys(hgu133aENSEMBL)]\n\n",
    "created" : 1463131195093.000,
    "dirty" : true,
    "encoding" : "",
    "folds" : "",
    "hash" : "1482602869",
    "id" : "737C178C",
    "lastKnownWriteTime" : 0,
    "path" : null,
    "project_path" : null,
    "properties" : {
        "tempName" : "Untitled3"
    },
    "source_on_save" : false,
    "type" : "r_source"
}
```

The JSON format files can be read using the `jsonlite::fromJSON` and the required information was stored in contents variable. When tried to read the commands using the [`readLines()` or `scan()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804392/4836511) the commands were being executed instead of converting them into a simple file. How to convert this into a `r` file ?

output(?):command in a `r` script/text file.

```
library(hgu133a.db)
x <- hgu133aENSEMBL
x
length(x)
count.mappedkeys(x)
x[1:3]
links(x[1:3])

## Keep only the mapped keys
keys(x) <- mappedkeys(x)
length(x)
count.mappedkeys(x)
x 
# now it is a submap

## The above subsetting can also be achieved with
x <- hgu133aENSEMBL[mappedkeys(hgu133aENSEMBL)]
```

Comment: `writeLines(json$contents, con = "/path/to/file.R")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone looking for answer to this question, the command suggested by @[Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342082/kevin-ushey) worked.

```
writeLines(json$contents, con = "/path/to/file.R")
```

Output:

```
library(hgu133a.db)
x <- hgu133aENSEMBL
x
length(x)
count.mappedkeys(x)
x[1:3]
links(x[1:3])

## Keep only the mapped keys
keys(x) <- mappedkeys(x)
length(x)
count.mappedkeys(x)
x # now it is a submap

## The above subsetting can also be achieved with
x <- hgu133aENSEMBL[mappedkeys(hgu133aENSEMBL)]
```